# Search percent matching text in html text

Tags: php

There is any way for comparing strings and get result in following manner.

**Text is Found** `eg. abc = abc`

*or* **Text is found but slightly different** `eg. abc = abd`

*or* **Text not found**  `eg. abc = xyz`

Comment: Sorry bro did not get your point ?? What exactly you want ?

Comment: text and html predefined! I don't know how regex may help. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of removing the html tags with [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and then calculate the similarity between the two strings with [similar_text()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php):

```
$text = 'Test paragraph';
$html = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';

$stripped_html = strip_tags($html); // Remove html tags
similar_text($stripped_html, $text, $percentage); // Calculating ...
echo $percentage;
```